# Get roles\scopes for logged in user

Tags: keycloak

Is there a way to retrieve the roles\scopes for a logged in user?

I am using the JavaScript adapter and am using the user profile function and notice there are no scope properties present.

Is there another end point I can hit instead? I had a look through the admin rest api docs and couldn't spot any thing obvious.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The roles are not in a scope property. In any server running Keycloak, go to `/auth/js/keycloak.js` to get the JavaScript adapter.  In there you'll see some code like:

```
kc.hasRealmRole = function (role) {
    var access = kc.realmAccess;
    return !!access && access.roles.indexOf(role) >= 0;
}
```

So you can access `kc.realAccess.roles` to find the roles that a logged in user is in.  The user must have been authenticated for this to work.

**Edit**

I'll admit that I'm looking under the covers a bit to find an answer for this.  However, the JavaScript version mirrors at least a bit the Java version to do the same thing:

```
Principal principal = securityContext.getUserPrincipal();
KeycloakPrincipal<KeycloakSecurityContext> kp = (KeycloakPrincipal<KeycloakSecurityContext>) principal;

AccessToken accessToken = kp.getKeycloakSecurityContext().getToken();
List<String> roleNames = accessToken.getRealmAccess().getRoles();
```

As you can see, there is a RealmAccess object that contains the role names in both the Java and JavaScript.  The Java code [is documented](http://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/3.3/javadocs/org/keycloak/representations/AccessToken.Access.html). Basing your code on the similarity of the code may not be a 100% guarantee but it does point to the Keycloak developers trying to keep the concepts similar.

Comment: Thanks for this, is this documented anywhere? I haven't come across any official guides on how to do this and am worried it is subject to change if not part of the official API